# angular js form showing validation alerts all the time

Tags: angularjs

I am really new to angular and I am just browsing its capabilities which are incredibly impressive so far...I created this simple username field validation:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>form validation</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="form">
            Name:
            <input type="text" 
            name="uName"
            placeholder="username"
            ng-minlength=3
            ng-maxlength=20
            ensure-unique="username" required /><br />

            <div ng-show="form.uName.$dirty && form.uName.$invalid">
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">please put your username in</small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.minlength">it has to be at least 3 characters</small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.maxlength">it can't be longer than 20 characters</small>>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.unique">this one has already been taken</small>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

however it just shows all of the validation errors...I am now sure why, I am also missing a model, but I again I don't know if it is necessary.

Comment: missing `ng-model` on the input???

Comment: @CodeHater could you please explain to me about creating this model and mapping it to something, it is something I am finding difficult to get my head around.

Comment: `<input ng-model="username" .../>`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hekaz/1/edit

Comment: @CodeHater sorry I had already tried that, but it still hadn't worked

Comment: `I don't know if it is necessary` - it is necessary to have `ng-model` on the input.

Comment: @CodeHater I see, I added the model it didn't work, I looked at sylvester's code and saw that I didn't have ng-app in my body tag, added that and it didn't work. I then added the controller but in a script tag but forgot to declare ng-controller in the html side and  it worked, why is this?

Comment: `ngApp` tells AngularJS which part of the document it should be active in. `ngController` is not a must to have. Your app should work even without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/hekaz/1/edit

```
<form name="form">
            Name:
            <input type="text" 
                   name="uName"
            placeholder="username"
            ng-minlength=3
            ng-maxlength=20
            ensure-unique="username" required ng-model="username"/><br />

    <div ng-show="form.uName.$dirty && form.uName.$invalid">
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">please put your username in</small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.minlength">it has to be at least 3 characters </small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.maxlength">it can't be longer than 20 characters</small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.unique">this one has already been taken</small>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: @sylvester I will accept this as the answer, but please could you explain something to me, I add ng-app in my body tag, which I was missing, it still didn't work, please note that at this point I had added ng-model. After that I added the controller and it worked fine, but I didn't declare ng-controller at all...so why is it that it worked at that point?

Comment: @user2405469 you don't have declare model in your controller please read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed three things.

1.You miss ng-app on the html tag:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

2.You miss a controller, ie:

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    function ControllerCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.username='';
    };
</script>
```

3.You miss ng-model in your input:

```
ng-model="username"
```

Full working code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <title>form validation</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
            function ControllerCtrl ($scope) {
                $scope.username='';
            };
        </script>
   </head>

    <body>
        <form name="form">
            Name:
            <input type="text" 
            name="uName"
            placeholder="username"
            ng-minlength=3
            ng-maxlength=20
            ensure-unique="username" required ng-model="username"/><br />

            <div ng-show="form.uName.$dirty && form.uName.$invalid">
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">please put your username in</small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.minlength">it has to be at least 3 characters</small>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.maxlength">it can't be longer than 20 characters</small>>
                <small ng-show="form.uName.$error.unique">this one has already been taken</small>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @jyparask after sylvester posted his code I noticed those three differences straight away, my current question to him and CodeHater is, after adding ng-app to my body tag it didn't work as well as the ng-model to my input. I added the controller into a script tag but didn't declare ng-controller in a div tag or anything (because I forgot) and it worked, why was it so necessary to have the controller there for this to work?

Comment: Actuall, you should declare it as an Angular app with this line :`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);`